# Plot dates with regular interval in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a graph in R. A snippet of the data set is shown below.

```
   DAY         B       C
2017-06-01   2946   197.5053
2017-06-02   5215   489.7401
2017-06-03   6305   740.6357
2017-06-04   6442   867.5795
2017-06-05   5758   1016.4603
2017-06-06   5037   1156.0188
```

The graph I am trying to develop is a plot of DAY (X-Axis) vs B OR C...as illustrated below.

```
plot(data$DAY, data$B, cex=0.5, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Revenue")
```

The variables runs for about 3 months. I am having challenges representing the intervals on the x-Axis as I want. 
What I want to do is:
format: show day and month;
intervals: every 5 days.

It has been difficult finding a solution on Base R. Most recommendations point to some complicated package and code, which is difficult to understand or apply. 
Anyone with a simple solution?

Thanks.

Comment: ggplot2 is actually really straightforward if you take the time to work through the examples (I'm assuming that's the "complicated" package). And there are numerous examples on SO for how to use it to change axis labels.

Comment: It actually is the complicated package I had in mind. I so far do most of my programming on base R. Maybe I would have another look at it @hrbrmstr thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2018-11-11)

data_frame(
  DAY = seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), as.Date("2017-08-31"), "1 day"),
  B = sample(1000:6000, length(DAY)),
  C = abs(rnorm(length(DAY))) * 1000
) -> sample_data

ggplot(sample_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DAY, y = B), shape = 21) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "5 days", date_labels = "%b\n%d") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Revenue") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

You claim:

```
plot(data$DAY, data$B, cex=0.5, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Revenue")
```

is easier. I'll grant you it defaults to a scatterplot but now you want to do something that's going to require calling more base plot functions to customize the plot so you don't get much for free.

- `ggplot` is only _two more letters`than`plot`
- You get to specify the data frame *once* vs have to constantly `$` reference columns
- `plot` defaults to shape 21 but you'd need to use that same parameter in base plots to use different shapes so there's no difference
- `geom_point()` sounds pretty straightforward to me
- the `scale_x_date()` line looks pretty straightforward to me
- theme-ing does take some reading and practice, just like anything worthwhile

Comment: It actual is much easier.  Thanks again. This works.